# How To Center Navigation Bar And Position Atop Bottom Section of Banner Image

Tags: css, navbar

Just a forewarning, I am new to HTML and CSS.  Please be patient with my inquiry here.

I am attempting to center the navigation bar while overlapping it on the bottom side of the banner.  I have a banner image at the top and a background image for the main content which is positioned just below the nav bar.  I've attempted to add the following:

```
ul.navbar li {
 float: left}
```

This floated the nav bar directly underneath the main body background instead of above everything. In order to get the list in a horizontal format i used

```
ul.navbar li {
 display: inline-table}
```

This was the only variation that would give me the correct horizontal format I was looking for.  Now I just need it centered and overlaid on the bottom end of my banner image.  Any suggestions?  My HTML and CSS is as follows:

CSS:

```
body {

padding-left: 9em;

font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;

color: #6699FF;

background-color: white 

}

div#contentareamain1 {

background: url(contentareamain1.png) no-repeat;

background-color: white;

color: white;

height: 634px;

position: relative;

}

div#contentareamain1text {

position: relative;

height: auto;

width: 700px;

left: 5em;

top: 4em;

}

#header {

float:left;

width:100%;

height:87px;

}

.wrap {

position:relative;

margin:0 ;

}

ul.navbar {

list-style-type: none;

padding: 0.3em;

margin: 0;

top: 2em;

left: 5em;

width: 15em;

}

h1 {

font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, Arial, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif 

}

ul.navbar li {

background: rgb(157,193,255);

margin: 0.5em ;

padding: 0.3em;

border-bottom: 1em solid black; 

text-align: center;

display: inline-table;

}

ul.navbar a:hover {

color: blue;

background-color: #00FFFF;

}

ul.navbar a {

text-decoration: none;

}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="header">

<div class="wrap">

<img src="banner.png"/>

</div><ul class="navbar">

<p> <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> </p>

<p> <li><a href="services.html">Services</a> </p>

<p> <li><a href="inspireme.html">Training</a> </p>

</ul>

<div id="contentareamain1" no-repeat>

<div id="contentareamain1text"><p>

</p></div>

</div>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First you should check your HTML structure – it seems there is a missing closing DIV tag and you should delete the wrapping P elements around the list elements.

Try this:

```
<div id="header">
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="banner.png"/>
</div>
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="inspireme.html">Training</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

After you just need to give your header image this CSS:

```
 display:block; margin:0 auto; position:relative;
```

and the ul.navbar needs something like this:

```
 margin:0 auto; float:none; position:relative; top:-35px; width:500px;
```

and you should delete the relative position of your div#contentareamain1 to get this code work.

```
 div#contentareamain1 { (…) /*position: relative;*/ }
```

Comment: This would work if the ul.navbar has indeed a known width. If not the margin:0 auto; will not have effect because it's width defaults to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

You should really visit [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com) and learn your HTML :)

The HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="" />
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">Link text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link text</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content-area>

</div>
```

Your HTML contains some `<p>`-tags who don't belong there. Also I guess you would like your content outside of the header?

The CSS
(I only give you an example how to place your navbar centered in your header, the rest is up to you)

```
#header {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    text-align:center;
}
#header img {
    position:inherit;
    z-index:inherit;
}
#header ul.navbar {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:-35px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#header ul.navbar li {
    display:inline-block;
}
#header ul.navbar li a {
    display:block;
    padding:4px 8px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

You can see the code in action at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/at7uS/) and play around with it.
Hope it helped you a bit.